# Wrong output on method to remove duplicates from linkedlist java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

```
public void removeDuplicates(LinkedList<String> ll)
{
    for(int i =0; i < ll.size(); i++)
    {
        String x = ll.get(i);

        for(int j = 1; j < ll.size(); j++)
        {
            if(ll.get(j) == x)
            {
                ll.remove(j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to remove duplicates from a linkedlist

The original LinkedList elements are
[a, b, c, a, a, x, y, c, b]

When I put it through the method, this is the resulting LinkedList
[a, c, x, c]

I'm trying to understand why both of the b's and the y were removed.

I initially though it might have to do with the fact that ll.remove changes the indices of the elements but I don't see why that would affect the other letters and not "a"

I know this isn't the most efficient way to do this but I want to understand what is wrong with it

Comment: You are changing the list while iterating over it; this is usually a bad idea. Collect the positions of the elements you want to remove, and when you found all, remove them in a separate loop. Or adjust the loop index variables when you remove. Also, `.equals` may be better for string comparison than `==`.

Comment: You could learn more by running this code in a debugger.  Set a breakpoint where `removeDuplicates` is called. Then, use "step into". Run the code one-step-at-a-time. (You may "step over" `ll.remove(j);`). Monitor the values of `i`, `j`, and the contents of `ll` at each step.

Comment: The O/P is correct that part of the problem results from the changed indices of the elements following the element removed. But, if you follow the suggestion from @Robert, a similar problem could occur.  I'd like to give the O/P a chance to run the code in a debugger before remarking on possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

1. When comparing strings for equality, the`.equals ()` method should be used instead of the`==`operator. Therefore, the following conditional judgment is incorrect.
2. In your second loop, you are traversing the linked list and modifying it at the same time. This may lead to unexpected behavior and even program crashes. After each element deletion, the size of the linked list decreases, but your loop variable j does not adjust accordingly. This may cause you to skip certain elements or access invalid indexes. To safely delete elements, you should use iterators or reverse traversal.

Try this

```
    int size = ll.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        String x = ll.get(i);

        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            String s = ll.get(j);
            if (s.equals(x)) {
                ll.remove(j);
                size--; // Update the size after removal
                j--;    // Decrement j to recheck the current index
            }
        }
    }
```

Or other implementation methods

```
    Set<String> uniqueElements = new HashSet<>();
    Iterator<String> iterator = ll.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String s = iterator.next();
        if (!uniqueElements.contains(s)) {
            uniqueElements.add(s);
        } else {
            iterator.remove();  
        }
    }

    System.out.println(ll);
```

Comment: There is no need to use separate contains/add for the HashSet: adding an already-present element to the set doesn't change the set, and the method returns false: `if (!uniqueElements.add(s)) { iterator.remove(); }`

Answer (score 0):

You've got at least 3 bugs.

1. You can't compare strings with `==`. `==` checks if 2 object references are referring to the same object. Not if the values are equal. You want `a.equals(b)`, not `a == b`
2. Your inner loop goes from '1'. It should be going from 'i + 1' - right now you are deleting its own element (if you find an 'x' at index 4, then you loop from 1 up to max and delete any 'x' you find. Including the one at 4.
3. By deleting, all elements shift down by one, so this skips elements. This algorithm is pretty bad, but if you must employ it, you have to go backwards - start at the end and move to the start. Or, adjust the index variable down by 1 every time you delete.
4. LinkedList is `O(n)` to visit. This algorithm will literally take years to apply to a list of a few million elements. There are algorithms that can do it in milliseconds. But 'rewrite the whole thing for me' is perhaps going a bit far.

A simple way to very quickly do the job correctly:

1. make a new `HashSet<String>` - these have the property that checking if a string is in them is fast regardless of how large they are.
2. Make an iterator and use *that* to loop through the list, using an iterator (`.get(index)` on a linked list is disastrous).
3. Per element, add it to the set. If that doesn't work (returns `false`) because it was already in there, call `.remove()` on the iterator.

Ditch the hashset. Which java does for you automatically, so there is no step 4.

Answer (score 0):

Your first for starts with 0, your second for starts with 1, and when the A in the list goes through A round of de-redo, what's left is {A,B,C,A,X,Y,C,B}, why don't you remove two A's, because after removing the first A, the following A moves forward one position, which skips the second A

When we start to redo B, since the second for starts with 1, B has already been deleted when i=1,j=1, and the following B will also be deleted, and the following data will be {A,C,A,X,Y,C}.

Then i=2, in which case the weight is A, and the following data is {A,C,X,Y,C}

Then i=3, then Y is removed, and the data after that is {A,C,X,C}

And then i=4, and then the list length is 4, and that's the end of it.